# ffmpeg rtsp over http not working

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, h.264, libx264

I put this conf on ffserver

```
HTTPPort 1234
RTSPPort 1235
<Stream live.h264>
Format rtp

Feed feed1.ffm
VideoCodec libx264
VideoFrameRate 24
VideoBitRate 100
VideoSize 480x272
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
</Stream>
```

I stream with this command

```
ffmpeg -i file.h264 http://127.0.0.1:1234/feed1.ffm
```

When I watch this stream I can watch via udp and tcp on this url:

```
rtsp://127.0.0.1:1235/live.h264
```

but i want to stream with rtsp over http(http tunneling).

How can I do it please??

Answer (score 0):

For requesting an RTSP over HTTP stream you would do:

```
ffplay rtsp://127.0.0.1:1235/live.h264 -rtsp_transport http
```